# Script Replaced with Scrap after Compiled

Tags: code

I have issues with, assumably, my compiler, turning any series of script into scrap code and rendering the original script irrecoverable. It renders the pdf file correctly, however.
No code to show, happens no matter the code or template present.

MikTeX, TeXWorks compilers, pdfLaTeX, pdfTeX, bibtex and others renders the same issues.

> runs script
> compiles pdf successfully
> replaces script with incomprehensible scrap
> original script irrecoverable

Comment: Please post the start and end part of the incomprehensible scrap.

Comment: If you are on a Linux machine, run `file <filename>` to ask Linux what kind of file it thinks it is.